# Calculating distance using linear velocity and time

Tags: turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The general simplest approach in ROS is to calculate the distance by multiplying the time elapsed with the linear velocity. As can be seen from this link http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Moving%20in%20a%20Straight%20Line

Since, i am a beginner in ROS i tried the approach used in games. Which is adding the velocity every time to a current_distance variable initialized to zero. But this approach doesn't work well. Code here https://pastebin.com/c0dJB4XQ

if i want to travel 5 meters in the first method, i will have to enter 50,000 meters to travel the same distance on the screen. I don't seem to figure out this anomaly.

I used turtlesim for my practice and learning.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269691/calculating-distance-using-linear-velocity-and-time./) by [sandhan26](https://answers.ros.org/users/28108/sandhan26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to enter 50,000 because you are running a while loop which adds the current velocity to a "distance", publishes a command, and then immediately repeats, with no delay. The while loop will run as fast as it can, repeating `distance/linearVel` times (ie, 100,000 times) and then exiting, no matter how far the turtle actually traveled. It just so happened that 50,000 was the magic number for you, and it has no real relationship to the desired 5 metres.

I don't know where your idea came from to take time out of the equation, but please forget it. Distance is always speed integrated over time. Never use anything else.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sandhan26](https://answers.ros.org/users/28108/sandhan26/) on 2017-08-28**:
I think i got your point. Thanks.